# Share Internet to Ethernet network from wireless connections with netplan

Tags: networking, ethernet, network-bridge, netplan

A computer 1 (on Ubuntu server 18.04) is connected through wireless to an access point and through Ethernet to a switch. A computer 2 (resp. 3) is connected to 1 through the switch (resp. the wireless access point).

2 and 3 need to communicate together. So, basically I am trying to a bridge using `netplan`.

For now, my YAML file is:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
      eno1:
        dhcp4: true
        addresses: [192.168.0.10/16]
        optional: true
  wifis:
    wlp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
      access-points:
        "ESSID":
          password: "PASSWORD"
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [wlp3s0, eno1]
      dhcp4: true
```

From 3, I can ping `eno1` and `wlp3s0`; from 1, I can ping no one. Machine 1 is configured with a static IP (192.168.0.5). Without the netplan configuration, 1 and 2 ping each other.

How can 1 and 3 communicate together?

Comment: Please, rewrite the question and remove "1, 2 and 3" thing.

Answer (score 0):

The current answer is that this isn't possible in just the config file. You need to enable traffic routing and proxy ARP and DHCP requests.

A full guide can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Jiab77/76000284f8200da5019a232854421564).