# Share wifi connection with ethernet adapter with Netplan on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, server, wireless, ethernet, network-bridge

I have `machine1` with two interfaces, `wlan0` and `eth0`.  `wlan0` is connected to my home network via wifi and gets an address on `192.168.1.0/24`.  I would like to plug in `machine2` to `eth0` and have it also connect to my home network on the home network's subnet, for example get the address `192.168.1.42` via the home network's DHCP.

I have been able to configure the machine to create its own network `192.168.2.0/24` and route to the internet via wifi, but I do not want the additional network; I would like to bridge the downstream machine to the home network.

I read a post (sorry can't find it) showing how to configure this with a GUI and [another post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037810/share-internet-to-ethernet-network-from-wireless-connections-with-netplan) stating additional software is needed.

Is this configuration possible with just Netplan on the command line?  I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 Server and would not like a GUI.

I have tried this netplan configuration, but when I apply it, the wifi disconnects:

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: false
    wifis:
        wlan0:
            access-points:
                "my ssid":
                    password: "secret"
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
    bridges:
        br0:
            interfaces:
                - wlan0
                - eth0
```

What am I missing in my configuration?  Or, as the linked post above states, is this not possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I'm dealing with a similar situation

Comment: No, I did not.  Nor did I pursue alternative implementations; sorry.